# Multi touch interaction within unity, OS is windows 10

Tags: touch, multi-touch, unity-game-engine

I can get single touch to work fine within Unity, no problem there at all.

I cannot for the life of me get multi touch to work at all. I'd like the simulate the same input as right click with a two finger gesture, and the usual pinch to zoom input, I've purchased easy touch but to no avail.

I've tried the examples that come with easy touch, and they don't react to the multi touch input either.

I need this to work within the editor because it's an app for a large touch screen monitor powered by a windows 10 laptop/surface 4.

Please help.

Comment: are you saying it won't work WHEN YOU BUILD IT, or are you just saying that WHEN YOU ARE DEVELOPING, it does not work IN THE EDITOR WHEN YOU HIT PLAY.  Which is it?

Comment: Both. It doesn't work at all. No multi touch input is picked up.

Comment: Turns out it's a windows 10 issue and I need to work something around that first before it'll work in unity. Will post update when I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to fake multi-touch. For our app, we need to debug a mobile app in editor for a 3d Viewer.

- Left click for single touch (Rotation)
- Right click for translating two touches (Translation)
- MouseWheel for two touch magnitude (Zoom)

It is not one to one with mobile but close enough.

```
private Vector3 previousPosition = Vector3.zero;
public void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
        OnTouchDown(Input.mousePosition); 
        this.previousPosition = Input.mousePosition;
        return;
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
    {
        OnTouchEnd(Input.mousePosition);
        return;
    }
    else if(Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        Vector3 tempPosition = Input.mousePosition;
        if(this.previousPosition != tempPosition)  // could benefit better check
        {
            OnTouchDrag(tempPosition);
        }
        previousPosition = tempPosition;
        return;
    }
    else if(Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel") != 0f)
    {
        float mag = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel");
        OnPinch(Vector2.zero, mag);
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(2))
    {
        Vector2 deltaPosition = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y"));
        OnPinch(deltaPosition, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

In the above code, you would have an InputManager that spreads the info to all listeners. You could trigger the event from there already.

OnTouchDown, OnTouchDrag and OnTouchEnd forward the current position of the touch so another controller would keep track of those values and consider displacement.

OnPinch considers the displacement and the magnitude of the touch touches. In mobile, this would be done in one place. In Editor, since two different approaches are needed (right click and mouse wheel), it happens in two places. When one is detected the other case gets a zero value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm wondering why no multi touch examples that are Unity based work at all within windows 10. I'll give this a shot and see where I end up.

Comment: Unity editor and player are broken with multi-touch on touch screens, surface tablet, etc. I've logged a bug with Unity.